# Checked state of RadioButtons in GridView don't change after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview control and I have placed a RadioButton in the itemtemplate. When I click a button I'm trying to get the checked property of the radio button. But When I click the checked property is always returning false. Please look into the below code and let me know where I'm making mistake.

aspx Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDepartments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"AllowPaging="true" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
      <Columns> 
       <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_Click" CssClass="button small"/>
```

Code Behind on button click

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDepartments.Rows)
{
   if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButton rd = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdbtn");
        lbl.Text += rd.Checked.ToString();// +rd1.Checked.ToString();
    }
}
```

Result will be False always in the label always. I'm using Ajaxcontroltoolkit in the application, Above controls are present in the update panel and I even tried to placing button and event in the triggers but the result is same. Please help.

Regards,
Nuthan A R

Comment: When do you assign and load the `DataSource` of the `GridView`? Note that you should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)` and not on every postback.

Comment: What is the datasource, Is data is coming from the Database?

Comment: Where do you use the foreach statement ? inside your Page_Load event or btn_Click ? if it's inside the Page_Load the value is always false but if you place the loop inside the btn_Click method then it should work fine unless you call it from the page load without check the IsPostBack property

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put If(!IsPostBack) in the Page Load. Now Its working fine. Thanks for all your comments. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you assign and load the `DataSource` of the `GridView`? Note that you should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)` and not on every postback.  So use the  [`Page.IsPostBack` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So assuming that you're using `Page_Load` for this:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindGridView(); // method that assigns DataSource and calls DataBind
    }
}
```